# Oracle trigger - restricting what can be entered/updated in field depending on a list of values

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, authentication

I'm trying to get my head around a bit of PL/SQL logic (I don't have much experience with it!).

A former colleague created a trigger on a table.  This trigger fires before an update on the table and basically checks to see if a user is in a list of authorised users in a seperate table.  If they are in the list, they're allowed to make changes to a certain column.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "SATURN".UWB_SFAREGS_ENROLL BEFORE UPDATE ON SFBETRM
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  l_user            CHAR(12);
  l_authorised      VARCHAR2(1);
  l_new_saved       VARCHAR2(2);
  l_mailhost        VARCHAR2(24) := 'smtp.xxxx';
  l_from            VARCHAR2(24) := 'xxxx';
  l_to              VARCHAR2(24) := 'xxxx';
  l_mail_conn       UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE <> :NEW.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE THEN
    l_new_saved := :NEW.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE;
    l_authorised := 'N';
    SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') into l_user FROM DUAL;
        SELECT
            'Y' INTO l_authorised
        FROM STUMAN.UWB_ALLOW_ENROLL
        WHERE (
            ALLOWED_USER = l_user
            AND QUALIFICATION = '9000'
            AND :NEW.SFBETRM_TERM_CODE like '9%'
        ) OR (
            ALLOWED_USER = l_user
            AND QUALIFICATION IS NULL
        );
     IF l_authorised = 'N' THEN
        :NEW.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE := :OLD.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN :NEW.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE := :OLD.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE;
        INSERT INTO SFBETRM_LOG
        (
            TERM,
            PIDM,
            OLD_ESTS,
            NEW_ESTS,
            CHANGE_DATE,
            CHANGED_BY,
            ALLOWED
        )
        VALUES
        (
            :old.SFBETRM_TERM_CODE,
            :old.SFBETRM_PIDM,
            :old.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE,
            :new.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE,
            SYSDATE,
            l_user,
            'N'
        );
        l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
        UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, l_mailhost);
        UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, l_from);
        UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, l_to);
        UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, l_user || ' tried to change SFAREGS enrollment status from ' || :OLD.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE || ' to ' || l_new_saved || ' for PIDM ' || :NEW.SFBETRM_PIDM || ' l_authorised = ' || l_authorised || Chr(13));
        UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END UWB_SFAREGS_ENROLL;
```

What I'd like to do is restrict this 'authentication' further and limit certain users to being able change the SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE field to certain 'CODES' based on a list of values.

If I select distinct on SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE I get the following values:

```
--------
RE
IS
RS
NS
RT
ER
SR
TR
RF
EX
EZ
EL
```

So the above is my list of distinct codes.

Now, my table of authrorised users literally just contains their username.  I'd like to expand this further to include a column containing the codes they can change to and from and then include this condition in the trigger For example:

```
"USER1" "EL, EZ"
"USER2" "EL, EZ, RX"
"USER3" "EL, ER"
"USER4" "RF, RE"
```

Hope this makes sense (to someone at least!)  Any idea how I'd go about this?

TIA

Huskie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [UPDATING('COLUMN_NAME')](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#sthref1247)
Try to use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEFORE UPDATE
...
DECLARE
  l_exists number(10);
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  WHEN UPDATING ('SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE') THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO l_exists
      FROM DUAL
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null FROM SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE WHERE code = :new.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE)
    ;
    IF l_exists = 1
    THEN
      ... -- perform the update operation
    ELSE
      ... -- ignore update operation
    END IF;
    ...
END;
```

`l_exists` will be 1 - if the `:new.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE` value is stored in the SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE table and 0 - if the `SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE` table doesn't have the `:new.SFBETRM_ESTS_CODE` value

P.S: adjust it according to your needs